# pchisq with right command but wrong answer

Tags: r

Calculate the probability P(X > 20), when X is chi-squared distributed with 10 degrees of freedom. Use command `pchisq()` to calculate the probability.

Save probability P(X > 20) to the variable ans rounded to four decimal places. Note that with argument lower.tail in `pchisq()` we can define if we want to calculate probability P(X < 20) or probability P(X>20). Using `lower.tail=TRUE` gives the probability P(X < 20) and `lower.tail=FALSE` gives the P(X>20).

This is the question i have from an exercise. I am using following command:

```
 pchisq(20, df=10, lower.tail = FALSE)
```

and rounding it to four digit but it is still not giving the right answer. Is there anything wrong in my command?

Comment: What is the expected answer for the non-stats savvy people?(like me)

Comment: I am getting answer 0.02925269 and rounding it to four decimals i.e. 0.0292, but still it is a wrong answer. Can someone please help where i am making mistake?

Comment: How are you rounding off and what answer do you want to get?`round(pchisq(20,10,lower.tail = F),4)`

Comment: I don't see the mistake - only that you should round to 0.0293 and not 0.0292.

Comment: okay yes, the mistake was in rounding. It was meant to be 0.0293. Thank you :)